# How can I use vim editor to write email in Alpine email program?

Tags: command-line, vim, alpine-mail

I am using the classic CLI Alpine email program, which by default uses the Pico editor for composing emails. Is there any way to use vim as editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure Alpine-mail to use vim, neovim or any other installed editor. From the main menu, select Setup, then Config.

Use down arrow key to navigate down to the Composer Preferences section. Toggle on "Enable Alternate Editor Command" as well as "Enable Alternate Editor Implicitly" by hovering on each of those items and pressing Enter so that `[X]` is toggled on.

Then navigate down with the arrow key near the end past the [ Advanced User Preferences ] section and find the line `Editor = <No Value Set>`. Alternatively to using the down arrow key, you can press W (WhereIs) and enter Editor. Press Enter to select Editor and enter a value. I entered `nvim` for Neovim, but you could also enter `vim` or any editor of your preference installed on your computer, then hit Enter again. To exit, press E, confirm with Y for Yes.

Now test it out: Press C to compose a message. The header will appear the same as previously. Enter a recipient and a subject line. When you arrow or tab down to the body it will switch to your newly selected editor. In vim/neovim you would switch to insert mode as normal for those editors. When finished composing your message, enter the normal `:wq`. Your message will appear in Alpine's Message Text field and you can send your email with Alpine's normal ^X keybinding.